# htaccess and redirecting sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I am creating a site with some vanity url's i.e.

http://www.domain.com/Email

What I'd like to do is use htaccess to redirect any subdomain i.e. the /Email to the main domain.com where an index.php will record what the subdomain is.

Is this possible or am I making this up?

Comment: A subdomain would be something like `email.domain.com`.  The `/Email` in your example is the path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean "subdomain", but I think you might do what you want by putting something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-_A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then, in your index.php file, you should be able to use `$_GET['id']` to determine what you refer to as the "subdomain" in your example. To test this, put `<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>` in your index.php file.